# CSV Survey results - python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a CSV with several questions, each question can have multiple answers (like survey results). Each question also has a corresponding question ID. At the end of my program I want to print the unique questions followed by each answer to only that question. I have tried messing with pandas and the CSV  module and still can’t get it to print only the one unique question, followed by the corresponding survey results. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Say the below is my CSV file:

```
36,What is your favorite color?,Blue

24,What is your favorite food?,Tacos

36,What is your favorite color?,Red

12,What do you do for work?,Teacher

36,What is your favorite color?,Orange

24,What is your favoirte food?,Pizza
```

I just want to print out each unique question with its associated answers like this:

```
What is your favorite color?

Blue

Red

Orange

What is your favorite food?

Tacos

Pizza

What do you do for work?

Teacher
```

Comment: Are there spaces in your actual csv file?

Comment: Try `groupby()` operation of pandas on `question` column and iterate over on the list received after this grouping, you'll be able to get what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over each `line`, and store the answers in a dictionary with the ID as the key. Then you can print the dictionaries out iteratively, and `'\n'.join` all your answers together.

```py
import csv

# Where to store your questions and answers
questions = {}

with open('data.csv', 'r') as r:
    reader = csv.reader(r)
    # Iterate over each csv entry
    for line in reader:
        # If you have not already seen this ID before
        if line[0] not in questions:
            # Create a new dictionary at that ID in questions
            questions[line[0]] = {'question': line[1],
                                  'answers': [line[2]]}
        else:
            # Otherwise just append to the answers
            questions[line[0]]['answers'].append(line[2])

for d in questions.values():
    print(d['question'])
    print('\n'.join(d['answers']))
    print('\n')
```

> [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=join#str.join)

Your output is

```
What is your favorite color?
Blue
Red
Orange


What is your favorite food?
Tacos
Pizza


What do you do for work?
Teacher
```

<sup>Make sure there are no blank lines in your csv</sup>

Your `questions` dict will look like:

```py
{'12': {'answers': ['Teacher'], 'question': 'What do you do for work?'},
 '24': {'answers': ['Tacos', 'Pizza'],
        'question': 'What is your favorite food?'},
 '36': {'answers': ['Blue', 'Red', 'Orange'],
        'question': 'What is your favorite color?'}}
```

Comment: Wyy would you want to use `for` loop when there's already `groupby` in pandas?

Comment: @YashasviBhatt Because it doesn't need to be done in Pandas. There are infinite ways to do this kind of thing.

Comment: It does needed to be done in Pandas if there's a possibility because Pandas is way more optimized then your code, why would you choose loops when there's already a better and more optimized method to do the same? Why did you used the csv.reader function, why not read it using normal file handling, obviously because `csv` has far more better methods than the file handling method, thus instead of using loops, use pre-built function because that's what python is all about.

Comment: @YashasviBhatt, If you would like to create a Pandas implementation I will happily `timeit` both answers so OP can see the difference. I chose to use loops because not everything needs to be done in Pandas (like I said). This method doesn't require installing any packages, and is a good learning opportunity. What do you mean about the `csv` package and reader? I have used it because it is the standard for handling `csv` files correctly? What do you mean *use pre-built function*? `csv.reader()` is a built-in and pre-built function?